# Very simple HTML/CSS card-based dashboard. Issue with cards filling unused space.

Tags: html, css, layout, dashboard

I'm new to web development and I'm trying to create a very simple card-based "dashboard" page in HTML and CSS.

You can see basic example of this (with the content cut out) on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thavtj6q/). As you can see I've got two basic card sizes, large and small, which are set to float left and thus take up remaining space using the following CSS classes:

```
.small-card, .large-card {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin: 2px;
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
}

.small-card {
    height: 122px;
}
```

But the issue you may have spotted is that the larger cards will block smaller cards from taking up space to their lower left, leading to gaps in the layout depending on the screen size or card order. It's clear to me now that the float property alone won't give me the result i'm looking for.

My question is, can this be resolved in a way that keeps the overall simplicity of the dashboard, without changing the order that the cards are defined in the HTML? I just want the cards to take up the top-left-most available space without leaving any gaps.

I have a feeling it's not going to be simple, but any suggestions appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [bootstrap grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) for this.

Here is some code using it along with your css:

```css
.small-card, .large-card {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-radius: 3px;
    height: 250px;
}

.small-card {
    height: 125px;
}


}
```

```html
<div class='row'>
  <div class="col-xs-12">
  <div class="col-xs-6 large-card">1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class='row'>
     <div class="col-xs-12 small-card">2</div>
     </div>
      <div class='row'>
      <div class="col-xs-12 small-card">3</div>
    </div>
    </div>
     <div class='row'>
      <div class="col-xs-6 small-card">4</div>
       <div class="col-xs-6 small-card">5</div>
    </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class='row'>
     <div class="col-xs-12 small-card">6</div>
     </div>
      <div class='row'>
      <div class="col-xs-12 small-card">7</div>
    </div>
    </div>
 
      <div class="col-xs-6 large-card">8</div>
   </div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'd hoped to achieve this without an additonal framework (I had considered bootstrap previously). However I may end up using this if I can't get the result i'm looking for.